# Mysql Connection with Phpstorm IDE

Tags: php, jdbc, phpstorm

For those of you who are familiar with Phpstorm I am using version 2.0.1 as writing this question.

I am on a Mac using MAMP. I tried to connect my database with Phpstorm but it is a bit confusing.

I went to *tools* -> *data sources*
when I press *+* to add 
and choose db datasource
it wants me to enter a "`jdbc://`" URL to the database.

The whole time until now I've been using `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`.

How do I get the db to connect with this socket thing? The software is amazing but confusing at times.

Comment: This is the official official JDBC driver for MySQL: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could just use the [JDBC connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). I have used with Eclipse in the past. Not familiar with PHP storm. Im not sure if it comes with MAMP so you may have to download and install it.

Comment: No i meant im not sure if the connector comes with MAMP's mysql installation. :-)

Comment: it does not connect

Answer (score 14):

On the top part of the add DB connection window choose MySQL, then click for download.

Then you can use the connection string `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename`. The connection string format is also contained in the autocomplete of the input box.

Comment: Per @Ma3x's answer below... don't forget to also turn on "Allow network access to MySQL" inside the MySQL tab on MAMP.

Answer (score 11):

I found this article useful: http://pro-cosmos.blogspot.com/2011/03/phpstorm-mysql.html

I successfully configured phpstorm to work with mysql but I used **"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306** as url.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a screenshot of my settings.

Thanks cweiske for 127.0.0.1, didn't work with localhost.[image]

Comment: yeah!! i agree, you have to first switch to ssh tab in mysql connection and configure your ssh. then you can specify that mysql connects to localhost. otherwise - what is your localhost!!

Answer (score 7):

The only thing you have to do is check the option "*Allow network access to MySQL*" inside the MySQL tab on MAMP (for your security, ensure you have the option "*only from this Mac*" selected).

[Here is a screenshot of the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC3tX.png)

Comment: Agreed- or at least this info should be folded into the accepted answer. This fixed my problem. Thanks @ma3x.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use Unix sockets with the standard JDBC driver.  There's nothing about JDBC that prohibits writing a Unix socket driver, but I don't know of one.

Instead, you'll likely want to enable network connections in MySQL and use the following JDBC URL:

jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you could enable networked connections in mysql and connect to the database using the IP 127.0.0.1 in phpstorm.

Comment: where would i put that? i cant even do that

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, JDBC does not support Unix domain sockets. You have to connect over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

For socket connecting use a 8889 port. Example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/
```