# IDEA Mysql connect failed

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

1. I confirm my username and password is right and i can login success at cmd

   [image]
2. But when i login at IDEA with the same username and password . the result is failed

   [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Connection with Phpstorm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673080/mysql-connection-with-phpstorm-ide)

Comment: can you show us your code please

Comment: Double check connection parameters, e.g. in IDE you are specifying the database to connect to, but not in console. Check that this uses is allowed to login into "hibernate" database. Also double check you are connecting to the the same MySQL instance (to which you connect from terminal). Try also re-creating the data source from scratch in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Andrey said
Login success in console dose not means that login success in everywhere
when i try to login in Mysql Workbeanch is failed;
so i uninstall Mysql and try to install it again
the IDEA can login database success