# SSH Tunnel MySQL Connection with socket-connection via PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, sockets, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, ssh-tunnel

By default, Database Manager from PhpStorm works well. But currently on a special Provider (1u1.de) I have some trouble to got this work.

I can connect to the Provider via SSH. If I want to connect to MySQL database, I have to use:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=dbo123123123 -S /tmp/mysql5.sock --password='123123123';
```

That's works well via CLI on Server, but I didn't find a way to connect via PhpStorm to this Database.

For me it seems that the "socket-connection" may be the Problem. Does anybody have a clue how to got this to work?

---

## Part of the Solution (?!):

Maybe a first part of an solution, I found that you be able to forwarding an Socket to your local pc as own socket this way:

`ssh -nNT -L $(pwd)/yourLocal.sock:/var/run/mysqlREMOTEMYSQL.sock user@somehost`

[Source of Information](https://medium.com/@dperny/forwarding-the-docker-socket-over-ssh-e6567cfab160)

This show me, that the Socket is established:

`netstat -ln | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3713865  /myFolder/mysql5.sock`

But I'm still unable to connect to this Socket with:

`mysql -h localhost --protocol=SOCKET -u'username' -p'mypassword' -S /myFolder/mysql5.sock`

Got this Error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 95 "Operation not supported"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql Connection with Phpstorm IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673080/mysql-connection-with-phpstorm-ide)

Answer (score 5):

`ssh -L /tmp/mysql.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock sshuser@remotehost`

and then

`mysql -h localhost --protocol=SOCKET -u'username' -p'mypassword' -S /tmp/mysql.sock`

seems to work fine for me

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. Only with Termux on tablet I can't connect. Error 'ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket ...'

Comment: Meanwhile works also with Termux. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH to setup a port forward, this will allow you to connect securely to your database without exposing it to the world.

On ssh, use the `-L` argument to establish the tunnel.

```
ssh -L <local_port>:<remote_host>:<remote_port> user@host
```

This will open `<local_port>` on your local machine, and then redirect all packets out the other side of the tunnel, destened for the `<remote_host>:<remote_port>`

In your case, you might want to try something like this:

```
ssh -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@mybox.1u1.de
```

After establishing the tunnel, you will be able to connect to the database through a local port.

From your local machine, not the 1u1 host,

```
mysql -u <user> -p --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3306
```

If this works properly, you should be able to configure PhpStorm to use the same address, `127.0.0.1:3306`

The SSH tunnel will need to remain open the entire time you need to be connected to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but didn't work for me.
This (https://medium.com/@dperny/forwarding-the-docker-socket-over-ssh-e6567cfab160) looks promising for me: `ssh -nNT -L $(pwd)/mylocal.sock:/var/run/mysqlREMOTE.sock user@someHost
`
This way I was able to create an Socket in my current dir. But I still have trouble to connect to it. Got `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 95 "Operation not supported"`

Comment: That&#39;s not the command I told you to use. Try forwarding the TCP socket instead of the Unix socket.

Comment: Like I told, your command didn't work. 
I connect via ssh to webserver, but if I'm at the webserver, I can not connect to port 3306, but only to /tmp/mysql5.sock. Think that's, why your suggestion not work for me?! I've tried it, got no working results.
Anyway, thank you for this hint.
This one I posted was another one I've found.

Comment: And it it 'didnt work' post the reason you think that. I am actively using an SSH tunnel to connect to my database, the command works.

Comment: I'm familar with ssh-tunnel to mysql. See my edited post 3min. ago. Seems cause of the socket-behavior.